# Union of two linked lists (ordered set of values and their frequencies)

Tags: linked-list, pascal, freepascal

We are learning programming in school on pascal and I have trouble understanding operations with linked lists. I would be really grateful if you could help.

I have two linked lists made of these records:

```
TYPE
    pa = A^;
    A = record
            v : integer; {the value}
            f : integer; {frequency}
            next : pa; {points to next item in the list, last item points to nil}
        end;
```

I want to unite them into a new linked-list without destroying the old lists.

The old lists are ordered by value (v) and the new one should be ordered as well. If the same value existed in both previous lists, then in the new list it will be only once, but with the frequencies (f) added together.

So my thoughts on how to do this are something like this:

- create function which adds a new item into a list (params are: the list(by ref), frequency and value)
- create a main procedure which loops both lists from one end and compares the values
- it takes the lower value and adds it into the new list, if they are equal it adds the frequencies and adds the item into the new list.

Would this work? How would you code it?

So I tried to write it up, here is what I got:

```
procedure Unite(list1,list2,var result : pa)
  var head,akt,l1,l2 : pa;
  begin
    l1 := list1; {current position in list1}
    l2 := list2; {current position in list2}
    if(l1 <> nil and l2 <> nil) then begin
      new(head); {head of our new list}
      akt := head; {current position in new list}
      while (l1 <> nil OR l2 <> nil) do begin
        if(l1 = nil and not l2 = nil) then begin
          akt^.v := l2^.v;
          akt^.f := l2^.f;
          l2 := l2^.next;
          akt := new(akt^.next);
          Continue;
        end;
        if(l2 = nil and not l1 = nil) then begin
          akt^.v := l1^.v;
          akt^.f := l1^.f;
          l1 := l1^.next;
          akt := new(akt^.next);
          Continue;
        end;
        if(l1^.v = l2^.v) then begin
          akt^.v = l1^.v;
          akt^.f = l1^.f + l2^.f;
          l1 := l1^.next;
          l2 := l2^.next;
        end else if(l1^.v < l2^.v) then begin
          akt^.v := l1^.v;
          akt^.f := l1^.f;
          l1 := l1^.next;
        end else
          akt^.v := l2^.v;
          akt^.f := l2^.f;
          l2 := l2^.next;
        end;
        akt := new(akt^.next);
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: You need to iterate over both lists at the same time. Find the smaller value of the two current values, move it to the combined list, then continue until both lists are empty.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That makes sense, but I am having trouble finding a good way to write it in code.

Comment: Well, it's your home work isn't it

Comment: The question is too broad since you're not showing any attempt, and we don't know what you know about the Pascal language. Do you know how to structure a Pascal function/procedure? Do you know how to write a loop using `while` or `repeat - until`? And for the linked list, do you know what the basic structure of a linked list is? Stackoverflow.com isn't a language tutorial site, so the assumption is that you can at least get started writing your program, and then ask amore specific question on where you're stuck. If you don't know how to do a `while` loop, you might want to do a tutorial.

Comment: @lurker Okay, I understand. So I tried my best and editted the code into the question, what do you think?

Comment: All the `not l1 = nil` should be `l1 <> nil`, or use `Assigned()` and `not Assigned()`. Anyway, your code is along the right lines. Good luck with finishing it off.

Comment: Did you try the code that you posted? What happened? What did you expect and what did you observe?

Comment: That your last else block looks dodgy.Probably you want else begin akt^.v  (2 more statements).... end;